# C# Unity паттерн Декоратор

Tags: c#, unity3d, ооп, mvp, декоратор

Пишу систему которая динамически добавляет функциональность объектам.

Все хорошо когда я работаю с **MVP Presenter** - когда применяю паттерн Декоратор - **Decorator**. Но когда нужно расширить **View** - представление без наследования, то я не знаю как добавить новую функциональность для классов `MonoBehaviour`. И вообще я уже сомневаюсь что **Decorator** подходит для этой задачи. Помогите рассудить пожалуйста.

1. Есть решение отказаться от **Decorator** но, это решение приводит к множеству вариаций классов наследников и соответствующих представлений - **View**.
2. Так же есть решение применить **Decorator** для **Presenters** но, сделать много вариаций для представлений - **Views**.
3. Использование **Decorator**  + что-то придумать с **COOP** - компонентном ориентированным.

Как это должно выглядеть в идеале:

Настройка объекта - происходит в редакторе не динамически и с возможностью сделать динамически. Я определяю объект с его конкретными **View** - базовой, и добавляю на него отдельные компоненты - которые должны управляться через **Presenter** динамически декорированным под эту **View** с его компонентами.

Comment: Возможно людям будет еще полезно узнать конкретно что ожидается в результате. То есть с некоей конкретикой что именно хочешь получить

Comment: [Design Patterns in Unity3D #2 - Decorator](https://tododes3.wixsite.com/plutocode/single-post/2017/11/07/Design-Patterns-in-Unity3D-2---Decorator) - это не то, что вам нужно?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, я почитаю с удовольствием !

Answer (score 1):

Я решил отказаться от **декоратора** так, как у меня просматривались **нарушения** ответственности. Когда я разграничил ответственности, стало ясно, что обычное **наследование** вполне покрывает все возможные требования. Потратил много времени, а мог бы не полениться и сразу проверить по принципам **SOLID**."

Цитата бородатых : "Как многие говорят, паттерны ради паттернов не стоит использовать."